# css cascade elements of the same class but hovering one

Tags: css, hover

I have corresponding html code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <g class="projectGroup">
        <g class="projectElement">
          <rect width="10" height="10" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
          <g class="projectElement">
            <rect width="10" height="10" y="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
            <g class="projectElement">
              <rect width="10" height="10" y="30" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

and hovering css:

```
.projectElement:hover > rect {
 width:100px;
}
```

try this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40fyo62j/)

why the hover is affecting the parent groups? I just want to affect one particular rect in group

Comment: because hovering the child is also hovering its parent and you have everything nested. Don't make the `g` element nested if you want to target them individually

Comment: i suppose the purpose of nesting tags has separate manner from css styling and it's independent

Comment: @Temani Afif as below snippets shows, nested element can be targeted individually

Comment: in the below snippet only `rect:hover` is relevant and here we no more have nested element since rect aren't nested but only `g` are nested

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one. Actually I dont't understand .projectElement:hover > rect:hover meaning, but it works !!!

```css
.projectElement:hover > rect:hover {
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <g class="projectGroup">
        <g class="projectElement">
          <rect width="10" height="10" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
          <g class="projectElement">
            <rect width="10" height="10" y="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
            <g class="projectElement">
              <rect width="10" height="10" y="30" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is closest solution. But could anyone explain `.projectElement:hover > rect:hover` selector sense?

Comment: @emilll this is the same as `rect:hover` and its trivial since you will target rect element hover and no more g elements

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way the SVG elements are nested, such that each `.projectElement` node is a sibling of each other, then you can get the effect you desire.

The problem is that CSS is surrounding each nested node with its parent, so hovering over a child means you are also hover over its parent.

Using siblings instead of ancestors allows the CSS to consider each element in it's own context.

```css
.projectElement:hover > rect {
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <g class="projectGroup">
        <g class="projectElement">
          <rect width="10" height="10" y="0" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
        </g>
        <g class="projectElement">
          <rect width="10" height="10" y="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
        </g>
        <g class="projectElement">
          <rect width="10" height="10" y="30" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please look at above snippets

Answer (score 0):

But what if nested tags are really desired? SVG Group tag is exact example of such nessesity. And each nested inner tag should have the same visual appearance.

Take a look. If marking the n-th nested element is possible, why we can't mark the actually hovered tag?

```css
.red {
  color: green;
}

.red:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <p class="red">first
    <p class="red">second
      <p class="red">third
        <p class="red">fourth</p>
      </p>
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```